# Having a huge chunk of memory on initializing an array of blocking collection

Tags: c#, byte, blockingcollection, memory-optimization

When I initialize a collection of byte array it resulted in a high memory consumption of 12gb memory.

```
BlockingCollection<byte[]>[] bc = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();
```

Comment: What is the `bc`? Is it a single `BlockingCollection<T>`, or an array of blocking collections? If it's an array, how many are they?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.